# woocommerce products view issue on mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have wordpress project. front page product slider which have products shown.I wanted to show 2 products on mobile view i try with media query but not fix it.anyone have any idea how to resolve it

Comment: Hello! Showing some images and what code you specifically used would make this much more likely to  be answered.

Comment: [wpcs id="5513"] This shordtcode use for hompage showning products.when view on mobile show 1 products i wanted to show 2 products shown one row on mobile view if you need i also share my project link with you.Thanks